# Dynamically attach image one by one with delete option in C#.net and Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to attach more than one image for a product. Here I am able to upload bulk of files at a time. It is working fine. But I want to upload image one by one with delete option. Here I am storing the file in root path as a folder and then storing the file path in the Sqlserver Database as "MyListFile/879_1/intel.png"

[image: listView]

Currently I am zipping files in a folder if they link download link entire set of files for particular id will be downloaded. But now they don't want to have  in a zip file while downloading. This is the existing code what I have now.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connnString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetMyFileList", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
    con.Open();   

    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        sdr.Read();
        absolutepath = Server.MapPath("~/") + "/";
        file = sdr["FileList"].ToString();
        itemNum = sdr["ItemNumber"].ToString();
    }  

    con.Close();
}

string[] words = file.Split(',');
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary;
    zip.AddDirectoryByName("Files");

    foreach (string eachFileName in words)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eachFileName))
        {
            string actualFileName = absolutepath + eachFileName;
            zip.AddFile(actualFileName, "Files");
        }
    }    

    Response.Clear();
    Response.BufferOutput = false;
    string zipName = String.Format("Enquiry_{0}.zip", EnqId + "_Item_" + itemNum);
    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipName);
    zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
    Response.End();
}
```

But if I try to attach file one by one it overwrites the existing one instead of appending. I want the result as follows,

[image: attachment]

In the same way I want to retrieve and display files one by one with download option.
Refer the image below,

[image: download]

Comment: Can u provide code snippet.

Comment: ok will add now.

Comment: If the bulk data you are uploading are stored in database, then you can create a single file upload functionality. Where once a file is uploaded you can update the file uploaded list.

Comment: I am trying that but for dynamic data I have a problem in storing that.